# How do you make a view drop dimensions?

Tags: matrix, julia

This is best illustrated by a simple example on v0.5-rc0:

```
julia> view(zeros(4,2),:,2)
4-element SubArray{Float64,1,Array{Float64,2},Tuple{Colon,Int64},true}:
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0

julia> zeros(4,2)[:,2]
4-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
```

The first returns a SubArray of `Array{Float64,2}` with only 1 column, but v0.5 drops dimensions. Is there a way to make the SubArray/View drop the unused dimension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tasos mentioned, it's a view *of* an `Array{Float64, 2}`, but the view itself is one-dimensional already. In fact,

```
julia> T = SubArray{Float64,1,Array{Float64,2},Tuple{Colon,Int64},true};
julia> T <: AbstractVector{Float64}
true
```

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up. I was confused by how it was printing. However, I am still unsure then why `y = view(ones(4,2),:,2)`,A=rand(4,4)`, `cg!(y,A,view(zeros(4,2),:,2))` gives an error. I assume that it was because of the fact that cg! can't dispatch properly on matrices (which was the reason for using the views in the first place).

Comment: In what package is `cg!` defined?

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas You should perhaps ask a separate question about that.

Comment: Yes I will, now that I realize that the issues are different.

Answer (score 0):

The `slice` function does what you want.
Also I did not realise there was a `view` function ... it used to be `sub` ... has this changed from 0.4.5?

Comment: Yeah, it's v0.5 syntax. I'll try slice.

Comment: man ... I should really update my julia installation. Oh, they grow up so fast ... :p

Comment: `println(typeof(slice(zeros(4,2),:,2)))` gives `SubArray{Float64,1,Array{Float64,2},Tuple{Colon,Int64},true}`. It's still not dropping the dimensions.

Comment: The "Float64,1" part of that type indicates it has worked. I believe the full type means "A 1D Float64 array, which is a view to a 2D Float64 array, as indexed by a "colon, int64" indexing operation."

Comment: I'm sure if you use `sub` the type will say `SubArray{Float64,2,...`   (or not, I dunno :p )

Comment: hm, turns out it doesn't, probably because the result is naturally a column vector. In any case, your result *is* a 1D vector. Try `:` in the other dimension to see the difference between `sub` and `slice`.

Comment: (you can also confirm this with the `size` function)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou In v0.5, `sub` and `slice` are now the same function, because the `sub` feature of not dropping dimensions is adequately replaced by the `slice` feature of not dropping dimensions indexed as `x:x`.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that yesterday while playing around on 0.4.5! And also the other way around! (i.e. sub dropped the dimension when indexed with : in the first dimension, as above). I thought these were probably a bug (given the function descriptions).