# A views implementation for cg! on matrices

Tags: matrix, julia

I am trying to use the cg! function from IterativeSolvers.jl on for solving matrix-matrix linear systems, i.e. AX=B for A,X,B appropriately sized matrices. Given the way the indices work, `X[:,i]` is independent of all but `B[:,i]`, and so this actually boils down to `n` different linear solves. Direct solving via `\` works automatically in this case, but iterative solvers like CG don't. I can easily do this with a loop on the outside, but I haven't been able to get the in-place op working. For now, my code looks like this:

```
for j=1:size(u,2)
  u[freenode,j],ch = cg!(u[freenode,j],lhs,Dinv.*rhs(u,i)[:,j]) # Requires Vector, need to change rhs
end
```

which gives solves CG with the appropriate lefthand side and righthand side. But the reason why it's not in-place boils down to this simple example throwing an error:

```
using IterativeSolvers
y = view(ones(4,2),:,2)
A=rand(4,4)
cg!(y,A,view(zeros(4,2),:,2))
```

which is:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching init!
(::IterativeSolvers.KrylovSubspace{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}, ::SubArray{Float64,1,Array{Float64,2},Tuple{Colon,Int64},true})
Closest candidates are:
init!{T}(::IterativeSolvers.KrylovSubspace{T,OpT}, ::Array{T,1}) at C:\Users\Chris\.julia\v0.5\IterativeSolvers\src\krylov.jl:66
in #cg!#23 at C:\Users\Chris\.julia\v0.5\IterativeSolvers\src\cg.jl:7 [inlined]
in cg!(::SubArray{Float64,1,Array{Float64,2},Tuple{Colon,Int64},true}, ::Array{Float64,2}, ::SubArray{Float64,1,Array{Float64,2},Tuple{Colon,Int64},true}, ::Int64) at C:\Users\Chris\.julia\v0.5\IterativeSolvers\src\cg.jl:6 (repeats 2 times)
```

The problem seems to not be with the views, [given the results of a previous SE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38724660/how-do-you-make-a-view-drop-dimensions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have doubts that you'll be able to avoid allocations, because the init! function is implemented as

```
function init!{T}(K::KrylovSubspace{T}, v::Vector{T})
#    K.v = Vector{T}[all(v.==zero(T)) ? v : v/norm(v)]
    K.v = Vector{T}[copy(v)]
end
```

and hence there's a copy anyway. Nevertheless, if you want this function to accept views, it should not be an issue to just modify the `Vector` to `AbstractVector`. (The function is simple enough that if you don't like to modify the package, you can just add a more general method yourself.)

Comment: Just pointing out that `rhs` *can* be a view. It's only the `lhs` that is affected by the `init!` method

Comment: `rhs` and `lhs` don't need to be in place, it's `x` (or in my example, `u`). `rhs` is the B and `lhs` is `A` (and that's pretty standard notation). But what's shown here is that the in-place version apparently copies `X` anyways, which would defeat the purpose of an in-place version. A change to AbstractVector should be put on their repo, and getting rid of the copy should as well. This sounds like it's now an issue for the repo. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it's not a "view" problem per se, the problem seems to be that the `init!` method seems to not have been defined in a way that can accept a 'view' (i.e. a SubArray type). The error suggests that "the closest candidate is"

```
init!{T}(::IterativeSolvers.KrylovSubspace{T,OpT}, ::Array{T,1})
```

(i.e. there's no method definition for a SubArray, only for a normal Array, and it appears there's no generic function / base case available to fall back on)

If you 'collect' the array first, then it works (presumably) as expected:

```
julia> cg!( collect(y), A, view(zeros(4,2),:,2))
([0.0752658,-0.693794,0.330172,0.437474],IterativeSolvers.ConvergenceHistory{Float64,Array{Float64,1}}(false,0.0,5,[0.249856,0.392572,0.401496,0.463142]))
```

except obviously that's of no use to you because you don't really get to change `y` as intended this way.

The only way I see around it if you're intent on keeping `y` as a view until that point, is to temporarily 'hack' it into a normal array inside `cg!` using a compound statement:

```
cg!((y = collect(y); y),A,view(zeros(4,2),:,2))
```

but, obviously, it's no longer a view at this point, so you'd have to update the original array it was a view into manually ...

Comment: The problem is that I am trying to avoid the extra allocations.

Comment: I understand, hence my comment that the "explanation" isn't really useful to you. However, short of modifying the `krylov.jl` sourcefile yourself, it seems to me you won't get it to work 'natively' with views. 

Obviously, purely from a 'convenience', rather than an 'efficiency' point of view, however, you could add another definition for `cg!` in your session, which accepts a `::SubArray` argument and calls the module's builtin version of `cg!` with the necessary conversions and memory management under the hood.

Comment: Btw, aren't you more likely to be using conjugate gradients on sparse matrices anyway?

Comment: Yes, `A` or `lhs` is sparse.

Comment: It's probably a better idea just to change the `Array` to `AbstractArray` and call the function anyway.

Comment: Also, @TasosPapastylianou, it is generally not a good idea to define methods on `SubArray`, since most such methods are general enough to be extended to `AbstractArray`.

Comment: @FengyangWang yes I agree. I'm just covering all bases (e.g. he may expect his code to be used by others)